# Короткий 1 сигнал bios в браузере FireFox (Arch Linux)

Tags: linux, archlinux, bios

У меня возникла такая проблема: если я ищу совпадения на странице любого сайта именно в браузере FireFox ctrl+f и он их не находит, то возникает 1 короткий сигнал в bios (будто он сообщает, что ничего не найдено). Как этот сигнал отключить? Я использую Arch linux с kde Plasma.

Comment: Установи звуковую тему, а потом убери у неё громкость на минимум

Comment: Я решил проблему. Эту надоедливую штуку я отключил в Параметры системы - Специальные возможности - Сигнал - Слышимый сигнал (выкл)

Comment: непонятно только за что тут bios помянут

Comment: Это системный звук PC speaker 1 (beep)

Comment: Я раньше не сталкивался с ним, вот и не знал, как он назывался